# jQuery to replace text in div when particular text is shown in another div (dynamically updated Shopify pricing variants)

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I'm working on a Shopify theme, and have set variants for different product options.

When you change between variants using the dropdown, the product price updates dynamically.

I want to be able to show the price in an additional currency beside the main price.

I've used the below jQuery to do this, but the price doesn't update live - until the page is refreshed (and because the variant choice remains intact, the price updates). It just doesn't update live without refreshing.

```
if (jQuery(".product-price").html().indexOf('18.000 KD') != -1) {
    jQuery(".dollar-price").replaceWith("$58.86");
}

if (jQuery(".product-price").html().indexOf('19.000 KD') != -1) {
    jQuery(".dollar-price").replaceWith("$62.14");
}

if (jQuery(".product-price").html().indexOf('25.000 KD') != -1) {
    jQuery(".dollar-price").replaceWith("$81.80");
}

if (jQuery(".product-price").html().indexOf('26.000 KD') != -1) {
    jQuery(".dollar-price").replaceWith("$85.04");
}
```

Updated version, still not working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".single-option-selector").change(function(event) { //HERE IS WHERE YOUR DROPDOWN ID GOES
if (jQuery(".product-price").html().indexOf('18.000 KD') != -1) {
    jQuery(".dollar-price").replaceWith("$58.86");
}
if (jQuery(".product-price").html().indexOf('19.000 KD') != -1) {
    jQuery(".dollar-price").replaceWith("$62.14");
}
if (jQuery(".product-price").html().indexOf('25.000 KD') != -1) {
    jQuery(".dollar-price").replaceWith("$81.80");
}
if (jQuery(".product-price").html().indexOf('26.000 KD') != -1) {
    jQuery(".dollar-price").replaceWith("$85.04");
}
});
});
```

Comment: You need to wrap these with something that lets the code know you changed the dropdown. Where's your code for the dropdown?

Comment: The dropdown is the one which Shopify inserts when you add variants/options to products - which might be the tricky part

Comment: Inspect that dropdown and get the ID from it and use that in my code in the answer below.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work - there are 2 different <select> fields which determine this. They have the same class, but doesn't seem to work using that. Will post below:

Comment: Have added in original post, thanks.

Comment: Try adding a `console.log("testing")` inside the change to see if the script is firing.

Comment: After `$(".single-option-selector").change(function(event) { ` then check in your developer tools console to see if "testing" shows up. If not, then the change isn't being recognized. If so, then your `if/then` logic needs work.

Comment: Yes, that does update console log

Comment: In this case, then none of your `if` statements are coming back as true. If you added an `else`, this would be returned. This means that whatever you're expecting to happen in your `if` statement isn't working as you're hoping. What are you trying to do?

Comment: When the KD price updates, I want it to update the Dollar price which is in a span next to it

Comment: So, this is a much different question because your `if` isn't going to remotely do this. What you basically want to do is get the value in the div and then perform some math (so you don't hardcode the logic) and then return that. Reasonably straight forward, but your code below won't do it.

Comment: I see - there will only be 4 different prices, so thought it would be simple to read the value of that div and then display something else depending on that. What sort of JS would I use to do this? I'm of the impression that it just isn't updating live (without refreshing the page)

Comment: Have got it working now - thanks a lot

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run your code when the dropdown is changed. Something like this:

```
$("#yourDropdown").change(function(event) { //HERE IS WHERE YOUR DROPDOWN ID GOES

    if (jQuery(".product-price").html().indexOf('18.000 KD') != -1) {
    jQuery(".dollar-price").replaceWith("$58.86");
}

if (jQuery(".product-price").html().indexOf('19.000 KD') != -1) {
    jQuery(".dollar-price").replaceWith("$62.14");
}

if (jQuery(".product-price").html().indexOf('25.000 KD') != -1) {
    jQuery(".dollar-price").replaceWith("$81.80");
}

if (jQuery(".product-price").html().indexOf('26.000 KD') != -1) {
    jQuery(".dollar-price").replaceWith("$85.04");
}
});
```

Make sure all of this is wrapped with a `document.ready`